# Difference between = and :=

Tags: operators

I wanted to know the difference between two operators:

=  and  :=

I couldn't find the ":=" operator on the list at https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Operators.html

Can someone help?

Thanks.

Comment: [`Set (=)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) and [`SetDelayed (:=)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) are explained on their documentation pages and compared at [`Immediate and Delayed Definitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html)

Comment: I gave my own explanation here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129902/how-could-i-define-function-with-function-such-as-coefficient/129921#129921

Answer (score 7):

You need to understand the difference of "Set" and "Set Delay" :

Let's make an example which illustrates this clearly.
I have a function:

```
f[x1_,x2_]:= x1+x1*x2
```

and I want to find it's derivative according to x2 at specific locations of x1 and x2.

```
m[x1_,x2_] = D[f[x1,x2],x2]
```

1. If you use use ":" before the "=", (Set Delay), it **evaluates the function when it is needed**, hence it will evaluate the function only when values for x1 and x2 are given.
2. The function definition without ":" before the "=" (Set) **evaluates the function before it is used** and the output is assigned to m[x1_,x2_], so if you input values in m[x1_,x2_] they are put into the **already-differentiated** equation.

If now, you would decide to put a ":" in front of the "=" for m[x1_,m2_],it will not work, since one cannot differentiate a function with respect to a numerical value (5 for example).

I hope that this helps you.

P.S. I encountered the same question once:
[How To First Evaluate A Differential Equation And Then To Input The Function Parameters?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128826/how-to-first-evaluate-a-differential-equation-and-then-to-input-the-function-par)

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response!

Comment: Your welcome ! Glad I could help. :)